# Itext place text in particular position with arial bold and some color

Tags: java, itext

I need to use a Arial font bold with color and place the text in Particular position,

```
Font name = FontFactory.getFont("file/ResumeBuilder/arial.tiff", 22, Font.BOLD,new CMYKColor(0, 0, 0, 175));
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("helloWorld.pdf"));
document.open();
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("Add in PDF document", name);
document.add(paragraph);
```

I tried using Paragraph but by using paragraph I am not sure how to place text in particular position or else is there any better way to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean iText version 5.5.x (in particular because the task has become trivial in iText 7.x).

Furthermore I assume you mean adding a short piece of text without the need of line breaking.

In that case look at the iText example [FoobarFilmFestival](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-3#152-foobarfilmfestival.java). The pivotal code:

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(RESULT));
document.open();
String foobar = "Foobar Film Festival";
...
Font times = new Font(bf_times, 12);
...
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
...
Phrase phrase = new Phrase(foobar, times);
ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, phrase, 200, 572, 0);
ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, phrase, 200, 536, 0);
ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, phrase, 200, 500, 0);
ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, phrase, 200, 464, 30);
ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, phrase, 200, 428, -30);
document.close();
```

`ColumnText.showTextAligned` allows you to freely position a text line at a given position with a given alignment and angle.

---

If instead you mean adding a longer piece of text with the need of line breaking, look at the iText example [MovieCalendar](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-3#157-moviecalendar.java). The pivotal code:

```
Rectangle rect = getPosition(screening);
ColumnText column = new ColumnText(directcontent);
column.setSimpleColumn(new Phrase(screening.getMovie().getMovieTitle()),
        rect.getLeft(), rect.getBottom(),
        rect.getRight(), rect.getTop(), 18, Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
column.go();
```

This code draws the `Phrase` in the rectangle `rect` applying line breaks where necessary.